# How do I impliment Ethereum fowarding functions without paying large gas fees for my business

Tags: contract-development

I am making a business and will receive Ethereum (and other cryptos), each time a user creates a order a ethereum address will be Generated for them to send too, then that is instantly forwarded to my address.

I know about the smart contact function that creates a new contract after someone sends ETH to that contract address, and have been looking at these transactions on Etherscan, however what I notice is that the Gas fee for making these contracts and forwarding is $10-20 depending on the average GWEI, which for example if the payment was for $100, this is large amount of it. Am I correct with this or is there something I am missing regarding the gas fee, as I see many other businesses using these forwarding contracts that accept payments for Ethereum worth $30-100 yet pay $10-20 for creating the contract and forwarding which is hardly viable.

So if anyone can clarify this for me or suggest ways to accept ETH to a newly generated address for each order that auto forwards.

Comment: Another option would be to accept payment at your primary address and distinguish the payments by appending a unique id, for example, the last 4 wei digits:  10USDT in wei would be 10000000, the payer sends: 10000123, where 123 is the ID.

Comment: that method wont be safe especially dealing with larger transactions as if two people send the same amount there is no way to verify whose was whose unlike individual addresses.

Comment: The amounts won't be the same, as the amount will include the unique ID suffix.

Comment: Yes I know but a user could accidentally send that exact amount even though its unlikely and thus we wont know who sent it.

Comment: Regarding the gas prices and your spendings, those accidental edge cases could be exceptable.

Comment: may have to just make the amounts for Ethereum include the gas fee, its annoying since its the only crypto that basically has a large gas fee to send and unlike bitcoin cannot send from multiple addresses using the same gas fee.